# mdadm - How does it deal with direct write to a RAID device?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

Suppose that I have a RAID 1 configuration using 3 devices /dev/sdb[1-3]. The md device is /dev/md0.

What happens if I arbitrarily write only to one/some of the underlying devices like in the following example?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb2 bs=512 count=10 && dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb3 bs=512 count=20
```

The RAID controller doesn't seem to have found any inconsistencies between the underlying devices as indicated by running the following commands

```
mdadm --detail 

/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 25 19:31:26 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1134592 (1108.19 MiB 1161.82 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1134592 (1108.19 MiB 1161.82 MB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun Sep 25 21:33:25 2016
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : u2:0  (local to host u2)
           UUID : 952d3545:9681da3d:58cc4024:75e1fc89
         Events : 81

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
       2       8       19        2      active sync   /dev/sdb3

cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb3[2] sdb1[0] sdb2[1]
      1134592 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

However, when I try to mount the filesystem of /dev/md0 I get the following error:

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/a

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Can the data of the devices under RAID survive this? If so, how?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, because 1 disk still has the correct data.**

You likely need to manually fail + remove the bad disks, re-partition them, add them back and sync the array... carefully.

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Mdadm_recovery_and_resync

Stopping and starting the array *may* get it working right away in degraded mode. But you'll still probably have to fix the array.

https://superuser.com/questions/603481/how-do-i-reactivate-my-mdadm-raid5-array

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0 
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Answer (score 0):

mdraid do not verify consistency of data, even in raid1/5. So in that situation silent corruption can occur.
But the worst is that I this situation mdraid do not know which disk contains correct data. If you damage data at first disk and execute repair of array, using command like that: 
   `echo repair > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action` you will be really out of luck. In that situation mdraid will copy wrong data from first disk to second. It effectively erase your good data in that place.
So always need to have good backup plan and remember that raid is not perfect or idiot prof.